# ¿Cómo comparar si dos objetos son iguales en términos de valores en JS?

Tags: javascript

quiero comparar dos objetos, digamos `obj1` y `obj2`:

```
const obj1 = {
  desc: 'descripcion',
  opciones: [
    {desc: 'desc1',
    correcta: true},
    {desc: 'desc2',
    correcta: true}
  ],
 otrasPropiedad: 5
}
const obj2 = {
  desc: 'descripcion2',
  opciones: [
    {desc: 'desc2',
    correcta: true},
    {desc: 'desc3',
    correcta: true}
  ],
 otraPropiedad: 4
}
```

En principio, ambos objetos tienen las mismas propiedades y la misma cantidad de propiedades.

¿Cómo hago para verificar si estos objetos son iguales en todos los valores que contienen?

Tengo entendido que usar:

```
const sonIguales = obj1 === obj2;
```

Solo me diría si hacen referencia al mismo objeto, lo cual no me sirve porque sé que no serán el mismo objeto (no será la misma referencia en memoria) aunque tengan los mismos valores y esta comparación va a fallar.